# Fastest way to remove borders from a document with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm looking for an OpenCV code (*using 2.4.11*) that would provide the **rotated hull bounding boxes** of all the images contained in a document.

The image may or not:

- have a border
- have a label
- be rotated (the border can have a different rotation angle)

Performance is critical.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**Example**

*Source*

[image]

*Destination*

[image]

Comment: take a look at [squares.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp) and [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/54256) an example modification on it.

Comment: Thanks. Done using RETR_EXTERNAL (first pass) and RETR_CCOMP (second pass), applying criteria on the contour area, shape and checking that two contours are distinct from each others (to avoid two nested contours to represent the same image). Used gaussianBlur and adaptiveThreshold  filters, as well as hull contour detection. Fir